# React Native Appearance.addChangeListener() does nothing

Tags: themes, react-native, android-dark-theme

I am writing my first react-native app and would like to switch themes like GMail does.
Indeed GMail get darker colors when we change the theme mode, or set automatic dark theme during nights, into the phone settings.
So I try to implement the `Appearance.addChangeListener` as explained in the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance) but unfortunately the feature doesn't work.

I am trying on Android 10.

How can I, **without restarting the app,** update the color of my application when the phone theme change ?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(changeTheme(Appearance.getColorScheme()));
    Appearance.addChangeListener(onThemeChange);

    return () => Appearance.removeChangeListener(onThemeChange);
}, []);

// This function is never call
const onThemeChange = ({ colorScheme }) => {
    console.log("onThemeChange", colorScheme)
    dispatch(changeTheme(colorScheme));
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to react native, too. Shouldn't the function passed to addChangeListener be declared inside the useEffect block?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem by adding this code to MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
    
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  getReactInstanceManager().onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
}
```

and for testing this feature, you can change DarkTheme in Android 10 and above ON/OFF.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here? Where is this code from?

Comment: There's an open issue and this is the suggested solution. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28823#issuecomment-642032481

Answer (score 1):

### use useColorScheme

### It will change the dark and light mode automatically

```
import {useColorScheme} from 'react-native;

then,for class component

componentDidMount() {
    Appearance.getColorScheme()=='dark'?this.setState({ theme: true }): this.setState({ theme: false});

  }
 componentDidUpdate(){
    this.listener =Appearance.addChangeListener((theme) => {
      // console.log("theme", theme);
      theme.colorScheme == "dark"
        ? this.setState({ theme: true })
        : this.setState({ theme: false });
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### useColorScheme

you can use `useColorScheme`, it will update automatically.

first

```
import {useColorScheme} from 'react-native;
```

then, in you functional component

```
const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
```

I also suggest to write your own custom hook to update StatusBar and NavigationBar on colorScheme changed